# Is it OK to use Stack Overflow to document use cases of my new library?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I see Stack Overflow invites users to answer their own questions as a way to "blog" about a given project.

Is it still okay to do so? What are the limits of this practice?

Comment: The rules are nice and simple.  If you're going to answer your own question, the question still needs to be a good question, and should be evaluated just like any other question, even if the author hadn't answered it.  Likewise, the answer needs to be a good answer, and will be evaluated just like any other answer as if it weren't written by the question author.  Doing this is *really* hard.  Most people tend to be really bad at asking good quesitons when they already know the answer, and then providing an answer as if the question has been asked by someone else, so be very careful.

Comment: Would also have to be careful that you properly disclose that you're the author.

Comment: Note that kevin means that you'd need to disclose your affiliation with the library, or risk breaking the promotion rules, not disclosing that you're the author of the question when posting an answer (or vice versa) which is not necessary.  There are even more restrictions than just disclosure on self promotion to ensure it's done appropriately; see [the relevant help center section for details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: It seems to me like reputation farming and SEO.

Comment: For full disclosure, I asked questions that are basically "Why ReduxJS?", "Why actions in Redux?" etc... but nobody wants to answers that kinds of question because they are lazy or because they are too board. Most reply are quotes of the documentation. Nobody argues anything. Even if in this case the winner (Redux) was chosen among several implementations no where I can find the rational for that. So I started a new project where I do things the way I want. Now, I can't get feedback on it. Because "it's too hard to enter into the subject" even for redux/reactjs veterans.

Comment: and my framework is 300 SLOC :/

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/